# Unable to see Samba shares in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-shares, nas, samba

I have a NAS server running Ubuntu server 14.04.5 (Trusty Tahr) and Samba 4.3.11. To be honest I don't know all the complexities of Samba, and I set the NAS up by watching a couple of YouTube videos.

I have been doing some research, and I think that because Windows 10 uses SMBV 3.11 I cannot see the share, but I also read that this would be fixed in Samba from version 4.3 onwards.

I have four Windows 7 machines, two Raspberry Pis running OpenELEC, two HTPC's running OpenELEC, five Android devices and a Windows 10 Laptop. I can see the shared folders on all machines except the Windows 10 machine (build 1607).

I have tried to turn on SMBv1 in Windows 10 (as Internet searches have suggested), but this has not worked. Why can I not see the shares?

I am assuming that there is a settings issue on Samba (I can see all the Windows 7 machines on the Windows 10 machine and vice versa).

I have managed to connect to the share twice. The first was when I got the machine; it connected once and then again recently when I had to change the Ethernet cable for the NAS. It does not show on my network but I can ping the IP address, log in via SSH and log in via webmin from the Windows 10 machine.

It has left me scratching my head. The `SMB.conf` file is listed below:

```
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic
# errors.

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]
browseable = no
max log size = 1000
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
syslog = 0
workgroup = PHD
pam password change = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
passdb backend = tdbsam
usershare allow guests = yes
os level = 20
wins support = true
load printers = no
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
unix password sync = yes
dns proxy = no
obey pam restrictions = yes
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
server role = standalone server
map to guest = bad user
netbios name = NAS-DRIVE
available = no

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field

# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server

# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
;   wins server = w.x.y.z

# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).

# If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
# parameter to 'yes'.
#   syslog only = no

# We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
# should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
# through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace


####### Authentication #######

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller".
#
# Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.

# If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
# password database type you are using.


# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections

########## Domains ###########

#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
# classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set
#

# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the
# SAMR RPC pipe.
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
;   template shell = /bin/bash

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
;   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

# Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
# to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
# user's home directory as \\server\username
;[homes]
;   comment = Home Directories
;   browseable = no

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
;   read only = yes

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
# can connect to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
;   valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
  comment = Printer Drivers
  path = /var/lib/samba/printers
  browseable = yes
  read only = yes
  guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin
[Films]
 comment = Films
 path = /home/paulnas/Raid/Films
 browseable = yes
 read only = no

[Films 2]
 comment = Films2
 path = /home/paulnas/Raid/Films2
 browseable = yes
 read only = no

[Kids Films]
 comment = Kids Films
 path = /home/paulnas/Raid/Kids_films
 browseable = yes
 read only = no

[Music]
 comment = Music
 path = /home/paulnas/Raid/Music
 browseable = yes
 read only = no

[Photos]
 comment = Photos
 path = home/paulnas/Raid/Photos
 browseable = yes
 read only = no
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this helps:

1. Run Windows PowerShell as 'Administrator'.
2. Enter the following commands:

   ```
   sc.exe config lanmanworkstation depend= bowser/mrxsmb10/nsi
   sc.exe config mrxsmb20 start= disabled
   ```
3. Reboot
4. See the server on the network

Source: *[Not discovering Ubuntu server on network](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/26e5fd75-f3ab-4ffe-ace4-ed4ba96f82e5/not-discovering-ubuntu-server-on-network?forum=win10itpronetworking)*

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your answer could benefit from [more detail](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). Please edit it to explain how  your solution works/how it addresses the OPs question. In particular, what are these `SC` commands doing and how will that fix the problem? Thanks for contributing.

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What are the security implications?

Comment: All extra information about the commands are available on the other side of the link he provided. Someone essentially had the exact same question on Microsoft's Technet.